# $lookup on object array with table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have data object that contains array. And I have providers table.

1. if array's Id should equals to provider's table id `Id == id`
2. if id is repeated take the repeated count as `membersCounts` else `membersCounts = 0`
3. Add the `membersCounts` with data object

**data object**

```
const data = {
  Milk: [
    {
      Id: 1,
      name: 'a'
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      name: 'b'
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      name: 'c'
    },
    {
      Id: 4,
      name: 'd'
    },
    {
      Id: 52,
      name: 'e'
    }
  ],
  Grocery: [
    {
      Id: 8,
      name: '2a'
    },
    {
      Id: 22,
      name: '2b'
    },
    {
      Id: 32,
      name: '2c'
    },
    {
      Id: 42,
      name: '2d'
    }
  ]
}
```

**providers table**

```
const providers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 52,
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'active'
  }
]
```

**here javascript code**

this code is working good but I want perform this with mongodb queries. So that performance is good .
Is possible to do with mongodb query. I need to covert the javascript code to mongodb query.

```
getMembersWithVendors(data, providers) {
    for (var key in data) {
      var arr = data[key]
      arr.forEach((element) => {
        element.memberCounts = 0
        element.new = true
        providers.map((el) => {
          if (element._id == el.vendorId) {
            (element.memberCounts = element.memberCounts + 1),
              (element.new = false)
          }
        })
      })
    }
    return data
  }
```

**output**

```
{ Milk:
   [ { Id: 1, name: 'a', memberCounts: 5 },   
     { Id: 2, name: 'b', memberCounts: 1 },   
     { Id: 3, name: 'c', memberCounts: 2 },   
     { Id: 4, name: 'd', memberCounts: 1 },   
     { Id: 52, name: 'e', memberCounts: 1 } ],
  Grocery:
   [ { Id: 8, name: '2a', memberCounts: 0 },  
     { Id: 22, name: '2b', memberCounts: 0 },
     { Id: 32, name: '2c', memberCounts: 0 },
     { Id: 42, name: '2d', memberCounts: 0 } ] }
```

Thanks !!

Comment: post how data is stored in db

Comment: Large json file

Comment: post model and few data in json

Answer (score 0):

> *this code is working good but I want perform this with mongodb queries. So that performance is good*

That is not good idea to do all the operations in query, it may cause performance issues, because your input data is so big, but you can improve some things,

- `$group` by query `id` and get count, this will return unique ids and its total counts

```
let providers = await db.providers.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]);
```

- iterate loop of object's array
- find from providers on the base of id
- get count from filtered document

```
for (let key in data) {
    data[key].forEach(e => {
        let p = providers.find(p => p._id === e.Id);
        e.memberCounts = p ? p.count : 0;
    })
}

console.log(data);
```

[Repl Playground](https://repl.it/@turivishal/Stack-Overflow-65832334)

Comment: Grocey and Milk is dynamic fields.

Comment: okay i will try if its possible update you soon.

Comment: data is not a table it's a my inuput object

Comment: oh that is strange, you don't need to do all operation in a query you can do half part in nodejs side, let me check

Comment: 1. data is object  2. providers is fetched records from providers table.

Comment: I have updated the my custom function . your function membersCounts as 0

Comment: you have not implemented my custom function, there is no need of `providers.map` when you use my function.

Comment: I used your function memberCounts getting only 0

Comment: i have tested in local it is working fine, are you getting data in provides query have you console it? you need to debug.

Comment: from the providers table records returning correctly . when its comes to forEach function not rendering correctly

Comment: you have updated your function in your question what is `vendorId` have you used that id in my function?

Comment: i have added Node JS Playground link at the end of my answer, Click on Run after it open.

Comment: @AsZik have you checked nodejs playground? is it working for you?